# is_array for MySQL Select Statement with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a basic PHP function that I am working with.  Sometimes, it is passed an array of variables, and other times it is just passed one variable.  So, currently, I have something like this:

```
 <?
 function do_this($user_id_array) {
   $user_ids = array();
   foreach ($user_id_array as $single_user_id) {
       $sql = 'SELECT username FROM users
               WHERE id = $single_unit';
               while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                   array_push($user_ids, $row['id'];        
               }
   }
   return $user_ids;
 }
 ?>
```

My issue is this: If I call the function and send it only one variable (and not an array), it (obviously) gives me the following error: `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

My *question* is: How can I change this function in the most efficient way with the least amount of code?  Do I have to use an `if is_array()` statement and just create 2 SELECT statements, one for each case (array and non-array)?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wow. that's a lot of queries. What about to delete foreach and do something like

```
if (is_array($user_id_array)){
    $sql = 'SELECT username,id FROM users
               WHERE id IN ('.implode(",", $user_id_array).')';
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $users[$row['id']] = $row;
    }

}
```

Comment: You have to `mysql_query($sql)` first.

Comment: You should use mysql_fetch_assoc on result of mysql_query, not $sql and you missed the point of question.

Comment: @genesis φ: And mysql_fetch_assoc should use the $result. :)

Comment: Author wanted to make a query even if $user_id_array is not array, not just ignore it.

Answer (score 3):

I see several options:

- Pass an array even if it's one element long
- Test for `is_array()` and act accordingly
- Add another argument which states whether to check for an int or an array.

I'd go with options 1 or 2, as option 3 is error prone.

Also, there might be a better solution to your problem, you shouldn't have a single query for every user, you should instead use the `IN` keyword in MySQL, something like this:

```
$users = (is_array($user_id_array)) ? implode(',',$user_id_array) : $user_id_array;
$query = "SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE `id` IN({$users})";
```

Comment: hehe :D I lost my consecutive days because I didn't log in yesterday :((((((((

Comment: Haha :D - 90 days, 82 consecutive for me. going for 100 badge :)

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
$user_id_array = (array)$user_id_array;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!is_array($user_id_array))
    $user_id_array = array($user_id_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function do_this($user_id_array) {
    $ids = array_map('intval', (array)$user_id_array);
    $sql = 'SELECT username FROM users
            WHERE id IN(' . implode(',', $ids) . ')';
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $usernames = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       $usernames[] = row['id'];
    }
    return $usernames;
}
```

First line makes sure that you have an array (`(array)$user_id_array`) and that all values are valid integers. Then a single SQL query is executed for all user ids.